# API to get product description from UPC

Tags: barcode

Once i get the UPC code how can i get the Product Description like name, mrp etc..,
I saw a similar question, there the answer was this link: http://www.upcdatabase.org/api.php
but that site is not useful anymore i guess, there must be an API to find out the product details. someone help please.

Comment: Hey did you solve this issue. I am looking for something similar. I am in india and wanted to scan barcode and get product details. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try http://www.digit-eyes.com.   They have about 27 million codes in the US and outside too.

Comment: they have app. on app store can you please specify link of api ?